How to check if Intel MPX extension is enabled if my CPU supports MPX?
I am testing out Intel's MPX instructions on my Intel® Celeron® Processor N4120 which supports MPX. I have assembled the following program but it seems that MPX instructions act as NO OP? I was wondering if there is a way to enable MPX instructions.
My code:
.data

bound1 dq 07fffffffffffffffh
bound2 dq 1111111111111111h

.code one

main:
xor    ecx, ecx
bndmov bnd1, qword ptr ds:[bound1]     ; bnd1 = bound1
bndmov bnd2, bnd1                      ; bnd2 = bnd1
bndmov qword ptr ds:[bound2], bnd2     ; bound2 will change to FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh?
bndcl  bnd1, ecx                       ; generate exception if ecx< bnd1

main endp
end

No exceptions are generated, bound2 value does not change as expected so I've been wondering if MPX are available but they are disabled? Is there a way to enable them? I'm on windows 11, I use MASM assembler and I assemble via the ml option from VS2022 cmd prompt. Thanks in advance

Try CPUID. Search for mpx here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID. According to Wikipedia (which isn't always correct) support is indicated by bit 14 of EBX after calling with EAX = 7, ECX = 0.

@SimonGoater I have verified with the cpuid (eax=7,ecx=0) instruction that mpx is supported (EBX = 00100010100101001110001010000111b). I've read that it can be enabled and disabled by writing to one of the MSR registers via the WRMSR privileged instruction. OS might have disabled it apparently due to the discontinuity? I will test on a different OS if that's the case.

You'll have to see whether bits 3 and 4 are set in xcr0 (see xgetbv instruction).  If they're not set, the OS has not enabled MPX.  I have a feeling that Windows doesn't support it.  Also note that MPX is deprecated, and won't exist in future processors.  Feel free to experiment with MPX, but I wouldn't do serious development using it.

@Myria, they are set. Eax = 01Bh = 00011011b after xgetbv with ecx=1. Since they are set does this mean they are enabled?

@TheodorosMpalis Yes, that means that they should work.  You'll need to set the BNDCFGU register to set the bound table directory's address (which must be 4096-aligned) and the low bit, which is the enable flag.  I don't know how you're supposed to set up the actual table, though.

@Myria I've found an article for enabling it: There are two config registers (one for Kernel mode and another for User mode) and one status register. The config and status registers are RW registers spilled and filled  by the OS on thread context switches. The Intel MPX runtime library, one of the  enabling SW components, initializes the config registers. What is "The Intel MPX runtime library" ? Is it a function I need to call in my code that does the job?
